# How do you send only the fields you want to update using the MERN stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

For example here is a MongoDB schema:

```
  const humanBodySchema = new Schema({
       Head:{
           eyeColor: String,
           noseShape: String,
           lipShape: String,
           hair: Boolean,
       }
    },{
    timestamps:true,
  })
```

When I send the post or put request I will need to fill out all of fields like so:

```
{
   "Head":
     {
      "eyeColor": "Brown",
      "noseShape": "Pointy",
      "lipShape": "Puckered",
      "hair": "0"
     }
}
```

What would I do If I only wanted to send the hair field for example?

Comment: Hi there. Please, can you share your backend code? The router/validation/controller for this particular endpoint to udpate humanBody.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to set the type property to "Schema.Types.Mixed" on the field. So the humanBodySchema would have to be like this:

```
const humanBodySchema = new Schema({
       Head:{
           eyeColor: String,
           noseShape: String,
           lipShape: String,
           hair:{Schema.Types.Mixed},
       }
    },{
    timestamps:true,
  })
```